# Chrome : my video start in autoplay when accessing the page, but not when reloading the page

Tags: html, google-chrome, video, reload, autoplay

All is in the title. When i access a page with a video tag, autoplay works fine.But when i reload the page, the video dont start.

What can i do to auto start the video ?

```
<video autoplay loop poster="the_poster.jpg" id="bgvid">
        <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm">
        <source src="video.ogv" type="video/ogg">
    </video>
```

i try to add a ?ts=**timestamp**.
i try also to start the video with JS but i get a "promise error"

Answer (score 0):

I've had same issue here and it solved by adding `muted` attribute to `video` tag.

For Google Chrome, according to [this update note](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes), `autoplay` with sound needs some conditions. However, Muted autoplay is always allowed.